# Side Navigation Drawer Item click not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview, android-navigationview

**PLEASE READ FIRST**
**BEFORE ANYONE MARK IT AS DUPLICATE QUESTION BECAUSE IT IS NOT.**

I have used Navigation Drawer, Bottom Navigation bar and a custom Action bar.

Bottom navigation bar and action bar are working fine.
navigation drawer also shows menu present under it but the items are not clickable.

I have tried all the answers related to

> navigation drawer item click not working

but still my problem has not been solved yet.
there is no error in the debug section.

[image: Image of output]

[image: Image of output]

**Dashboard Activity**

```
package com.vicky.sampleApp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    //android.app.ActionBar actionbar;
    TextView textview;
    TextView textviewTitle;
    private ActionBar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        Toolbar toolbar1 = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);

        setActionBarText("HomePage");

         drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
         toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar1, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.bringToFront();
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        toolbar = getSupportActionBar();

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);



    }


    private void setActionBarText(String text){
    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    toolbar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_appbar_theme));//line under the action bar
    View viewActionBar = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_title_text_layout, null);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(//Center the textview in the ActionBar !
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);
    textviewTitle = (TextView) viewActionBar.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_textview);
    textviewTitle.setText(text);
    toolbar.setCustomView(viewActionBar, params);
    toolbar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    toolbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
/*
private NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mSideNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_camera:
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this,AboutUs.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_slideshow:
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_manage:
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "Nav_share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                Toast.makeText(Dashboard.this, "nav_send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
};
*/
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    setActionBarText("Home");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_appointments:
                    setActionBarText("Appointments");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_category:
                    setActionBarText("Category");
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    setActionBarText("Profile");
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nav_manage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nav_share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "nav_send", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**dashboard.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/CustomTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav_bar"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav_bar"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: *`BEFORE ANYONE MARK IT AS DUPLICATE PLEASE READ THE QUESTION.`* sure sir

Comment: Sir did you find the reason why this is not working? I have added images to the question for the reference please have a look at them also.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Just put your `NavigationView` after `FrameLayout`. Check below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/CustomTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/CustomTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav_bar"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_bottom_nav_bar"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thankyou very much sir, it was really a silly mistake, few moments back only i transferred that section at the top.  SIR may i know the reason why this problem occured...

Comment: Because FrameLayout overlaps NavigationView.

Comment: @VickySalunkhe You know what. They make same mistake in AndroidStudio's template Drawer Navigation project! Thank god I found this answer :)

Comment: This answer is such a lifesaver. Spent so much time only to find out that my NavigationView had to be on the bottom of the xml layout. Android Y U DO THIS?!!!

Answer (score 19):

I was searching for different keywords but landed on this page every time. I had the issue that I could not click the navigation menu items.

I thought it would be easy to find a solution for those who are struggling with this strange behavior which is auto-generated by android studio 4.0 while creating a project with a navigation drawer.

I spent hours but at the end I have to find it my own way and that way was too simple. **Posting in the hope of helping someone**. My Layout was the following on which the item click was not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I changed to this , Just put the navigation view on the bottom and it worked.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    
    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: you saved me hours of searching, still it's a shame that Android Studio creates the first version by default when you create a new Drawer Activity...

Comment: This one helped me

Answer (score 4):

I too had the same problem. Just you have to put the NavigationView in the last part of the XML code.

Answer (score 2):

**You should call or include the frame layout
before next, the navigation refer to the code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```